# How to Select a tree item using UI Automation?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ui-automation

I am trying to select a tree item from an application but get "Operation cannot be performed". I tried using UI Spy to select the tree item and get the same error.

> Element : "tree item" "Network"
>   Name : InvalidOperationException
>   Message : Operation cannot be performed.
>   Stack Trace :    at MS.Internal.AutomationProxies.WindowsTreeView.TreeViewItem.System.Windows.Automation.Provider.ISelectionItemProvider.Select()
>      at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>      at MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreApi.CheckError(Int32 hr)
>      at System.Windows.Automation.SelectionItemPattern.Select()

From UI Spy I know SelectionItem is a supported pattern. Here is some of the code

```
AutomationElement  Item = _ParentNode.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new AndCondition(
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Network"),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TreeItem)));

SelectionItemPattern ItemToSelect = Item .GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern) as SelectionItemPattern;
ItemToSelect.Select();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: InvalidOperationException just means it's not possible at that time for this item for "some reason": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.selectionitempattern.select.aspx

Comment: Is there any way to find out the reason its not possible and work around it?

Comment: In general, it's because the operation cannot be performed by any code nor by any human. Think about the cases when you, as a human, can't select a tree item. It can happen for focus reason for example.

Comment: One reason may be that the item is offscreen

Comment: @IvanDanilov so how do I scroll tree items into view?  The Scroll Pattern is not available for the parent tree control.

Comment: @Airn5475 you don't need scroll pattern on the parent control. Look for [ScrollItem pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/uiauto-implementingscrollitem) on the item itself and its ScrollIntoView method.

Comment: @IvanDanilov tree item doesn't have ScrollItem pattern.  Ended up just making the window larger and it brought the items into view.  Now just struggling to select the checkbox.

Comment: @Airn5475 it has (just checked File Explorer folder tree) unless it is some custom control like Telerik or DevExpress in which case it is a question to the vendor, not about UIA

Answer (score 0):

Do verify programmatically if the automation element 'Item' supports SelectionPattern control pattern or not.

```
private SelectionPattern GetSelectionPattern(
AutomationElement targetControl)
{
SelectionPattern selectionPattern = null;

try
{
    selectionPattern =
        targetControl.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionPattern.Pattern)
        as SelectionPattern;
}
// Object doesn't support the SelectionPattern control pattern 
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    return null;
}

return selectionPattern;
```

}

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604455(v=vs.110).aspx